# Classify all regular polyhedra

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, platonic-solids

How can we classify all regular polyhedra? I know that there are five regular polyhedra as a hint. Thanks.

Comment: You mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid)?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: Yes

Comment: What's your definition of polyhedron? What does this have to do with algebraic topology?

Comment: Regularity has nothing to do with homeomorphism. regularity is a geometric concept, not a topological one.

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion. I heard the question in a Algebraic Topology class. I think this question is combinatorial.

Comment: For a broader context, you might want to look at "uniform polyhedra": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron .

Comment: @ErginSuer All you need from Algebraic Topology is the Euler formula $V - E + F = 2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your polyhedron is regular, all faces are regular $n$-gons with some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $3\leq n$. Look at the $k \geq 3$ faces meeting at an vertex (because of regularity, the choice of the vertex doesn't matter). Each of the $k$ faces has an internal angle of $(\pi - 2\pi/n)/2 = \pi(1/2 - 1/n) = \pi(n-2)/n$. Since your polyhedron is convex, you get $k \pi(n-2)/n < 2\pi$, or equivalently $k < 2n/(n-2)$. There are five solutions to these conditions on $n,k$: $$(n,k)\in\{(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(4,3),(5,3)\}$$
Each solution corresponds to one of the $5$ Platonian solids.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask about "all" regular polyhedra, the answer must depend on what you mean by a "polyhedron". In Euclidean space there are five regular *convex* polyhedra, the Platonic solids, and four regular *stars*, the Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra. There are also a good many infinite polyhedra or *apeirohedra* known as the Grünbaum-Dress polyhedra.

All these regular polyhedra, bar one subsequently discovered by Dress, are described in Grünbaum, B.; "Regular polyhedra - old and new", *Aequationes Math.* Vol 16, 1977, pp.1-20.

For a more elegant treatment confirming Dress' list, see McMullen, P. and Schulte, E. "Regular Polytopes in Ordinary Space", *Discrete & Computational Geometry*, Vol 17, No 4, June 1997, pp 449–478.

In other kinds of space there are many more, including regular projective polyhedra (such as the hemicube) and regular hyperbolic polyhedra.